# saltstack, multi-line pillar items interpolated into template

Tags: yaml, salt-stack

I have a pillar that looks like this:

```
inline_blocks:
  the_seven: |
    dog cat horse cow
    ardvaark beatle snail
```

which I then want to insert into a file

```
{% set inline_block = pillar['inline_blocks'].get(val, '') %}
/etc/animals.conf:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://farm/animals.conf
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 644
    - template: jinja
    - defaults:
        extras: {{ inline_block }}
```

and then in `animals.conf`,

```
{{ extras }}
```

I expect that if the key `val` is in `inline_blocks`, then its value will be interpolated in.  If it's not, an empty string will be interpolated in.

Indeed, that's what happens if I write the defaults statement explicitly:

```
    - defaults:
        extras: |
          dog cat horse cow
          ardvaark beatle snail
```

but as written above, I get the error `could not find expected ':'`.

As a reality check, `pillar.items` happily retrieves the pillar entry, so (1) the pillar entry can be retrieved, and (2) the value can be interpolated, but (X) the multi-line value in the .sls file is causing problems.

Any pointers what the right syntax is to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was discussed in a [bug](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/5480) as well, but for the `content` parameter. It seems to apply to multi-line YAML blocks passed as `defaults` or `context` also.

Since you are using a Jinja template file as a source, we can easily fetch pillar data from template itself (as one of the comments suggests in above link).

Considering pillar as:

```yaml
inline_blocks:
  val: |
    dog cat horse cow
    ardvaark beatle snail
```

Then the `animals.conf.j2` template as:

```
{{ salt.pillar.get('inline_blocks:val', default="foo") }}
```

*Note*: If this pillar data is assured to be always defined, we might even use `pillar['inline_blocks']['val']` in the template.

Rendered with a state like:

```yaml
create-animals-conf:
  file.managed:
    - name: /tmp/animals.conf
    - source: salt://animals.conf.j2
    - mode: 0664
    - template: jinja
```

Should yield the template as you expect:

```
$ cat /tmp/animals.conf
dog cat horse cow
ardvaark beatle snail
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that

```yaml
    - defaults:
        extras: {{ inline_block }}
```

is processed into

```yaml
    - defaults:
        extras: dog cat horse cow
ardvaark beatle snail
```

So YAML tries to parse the second line as another top-level key. However, the `:` marking the end of this key never comes, hence the error.

To fix it, do this:

```yaml
    - defaults: 
        extras: |
          {{ inline_block | indent(10) }}
```

`indent` doesn't indent the first line, but will add 10 spaces to every subsequent line.